# Only get node with unversioned changes - JCR ModeShape

Tags: jakarta-ee, jcr, modeshape, wildfly-8

We have a couple of nodes in JCR which are supposed to versioned at midnight. Of course we only want to create a new version if there was a change to this node since the last time it was versioned. Is there a way to get all nodes with unversioned changes without getting all, iterating over them and comparing the timestamp of the last change to the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCR 2.0 includes a built-in standard mixin, `mix:lastModified` that is defined like this:

```
[mix:lastModified] mixin 
  - jcr:lastModified (date) 
  - jcr:lastModifiedBy (string)
```

To use it, simply add it as a mixin to a node using `Node.addMixin("mix:lastModified")`, or if you're using a custom node type simply change your custom node type extend it. When you change one of these nodes, ModeShape will automatically update the two properties upon save. (There is also a built-in `mix:created` that has `jcr:created` and `jcr:createdBy` properties, and works in an analogous manner.)

To find all nodes that were modified after some time, issue a query:

```
SELECT [jcr:path]
FROM [mix:lastModified] AS node
WHERE [jcr:lastModified] >= CAST('2014-06-01T11:00:00.000' AS DATE)
```

If you need more than the path, it might be easiest to use `QueryResult.getNodes()` and iterate over the `Node` instances (rather than use the `getRows()`).

This last query will find all nodes regardless of type, so if you want to find all nodes of a given type (e.g., `acme:dataNode`) on which `mix:lastModified` was added as *mixin* and on which some properties were changed since some date, you need to use a join:

```
SELECT modified.[jcr:path], myNode.[acme:myDataProperty]
FROM [acme:dataNode] AS myNode
JOIN [mix:lastModified] AS modified ON ISSAMENODE(myNode,modified)
WHERE modified.[jcr:lastModified] >= CAST('2014-06-01T11:00:00.000' AS DATE)
```

On the other hand, if your custom node type extends `mix:lastModified` like:

```
[acme:customType] > mix:lastModified, mix:versionable
  - acme:customProperty (string)
```

then your query can be a little simpler and select from that node type (without a join):

```
SELECT [jcr:path], [acme:customProperty]
FROM [amce:customType] AS node
WHERE [jcr:lastModified] >= CAST('2014-06-01T11:00:00.000' AS DATE)
```

After all, the `mix:lastModified` properties are visible on your custom type and thus are visible in the `acme:customType` node type.